# Problem no. $7$ Section $4.12$ Krieszig Functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying problems of Krieszig Functional analysis section open mapping theoram. 
My professor doesn't bother to give or discuss any assignment problems. 
So, I am asking them here. 
Please give some hint.

> **Problem:** Let $T: X\to Y$ be a bounded linear operator, where $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces. If $T$ is bijective, show that there are positive real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $$a\|x\|\leq \|Tx\|\leq b \|x\|$$ for all $x\in X$.

My attempt - Right side is clear by definition of boundedness of $T$. 
It could be deducted by  bounded inverse theorem that inverse of $T$ is bounded but I am not able to prove the left side of inequality using it.

Comment: $x=T^{-1}(Tx){}{}$

Comment: @DavidMitra  I have to use that inverse of T is bounded and norm inequality on $ T^-1$ ( Tx) . Got it. Thanks a lot